# Input Text fields don't move cursor on mouse click?

Tags: java, javascript, events, gwt

I have an issue with all of my `Input Text` fields, maybe someone has an idea:

I'm using `GWT`, and just discovered that the text in of my Input Fields cannot be selected using Mouse. Also clicking inside the text does not move the cursor.

But giving them Focus using the cursor works. Selecting all with CTRL+A as well as moving the cursor with Arrow Keys works as expected.

I inspected the `TextBox` specific `onBrowserEvents()` method and can see, that click events are received well. Just somehow they don't modify the text input control in the browser.

I tested different machines and different browsers, which all behave the same. So it must be something in my Application.

Maybe somebody has an idea what I could have done wrong? I can't even imagine anything that could produce this behaviour on *all* of my input fields.

Comment: You modified the TextBox class somehow. We need to see the code if you want us to help.

Comment: Please check your panel usage. Do not use Rootpanel with Layoutpanel.

Comment: Are you sure it doesnt work?. Just checked in the showcase example, (http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicText) it works fine. Did you extend the class and changed any methods ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just turned out to be a CSS issue:

I had `-moz-user-select: -moz-none;` to prevent doubleclick issues for some of my components. I now excluded the input element from it and everything works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to solve the problem with selecting text and moving the cursor on the text in the inputs:

```
*, ::before, ::after
    -webkit-user-select: text
```